# Ubuntu missing from hard drive boot

Tags: boot

Ubuntu is the only OS installed on my Acer netbook.  Few, if any, problems until, with no warning, it vanished from the boot list for the hard drive.  I have been a ble to create a bootable USB to be ablee to use the netbook but have not been able to restore Ubuntu to the hard drive boot list.

As you can probabaly tell from the way the problem is described, I am a complete novice so any help you can give should assume no knowledge at all on my part and should be written as if for a simpleton.

Thank you.

Comment: What boot list?  If it is the only OS installed, there isn't a list.

Comment: Can you boot to Ubuntu..?

Answer (score 2):

If you messed up everything and want to correct things. This has an auto correct button. If the ubuntu is there it will find it, and it will work.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && sudo boot-repair
```

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

[image]

Otherwise system recovery from Live USB/CD boot menu.

Comment: [...]Ubuntu is the only OS installed on my Acer netbook[...] What is there to repair?.

Comment: It will repair the boot list, so you can normaly boot ubuntu

Comment: Yes i know, but if Ubuntu is the only OS there's nothing else, nothing is actually broken,  what is left to repair then?. He doesn't have a list because you need 2 things to make a list, there's no other OS=There's no list to be made=There's nothing Broken=There's nothing to fix.

Comment: What list if it's the only thing there?

Comment: "it vanished from the boot list for the hard drive. I have been a ble to create a bootable USB to be ablee to use the netbook but have not been able to restore Ubuntu to the hard drive boot list." -> That is his problem, the kernel is not detected, and not added to the boot list, he only sees memtest I think.
If you hold right shift, or had an error on previous boot, you will be shown a boot list, with memtest and ubuntu kernels, and single user mode.

Comment: There may be a list of kernels or other options like memory test.

Comment: If that's the case then someone please edit the question it reads otherwise.

Comment: All my machines have a boot list and most of them only have ubuntu installed. The list contains old kernels and memory test, if I remember well it appears when you upgrade to a new version.